# error when running play framework 2.0 on my mac (NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: macos, logging, playframework, slf4j, playframework-2.0

I'm just trying out play framework 2.0 on my mac. I've been using Play 1.x for a while without any issues.
I've downloaded the new framework, updated my PATH to point to the new version of play and created a simple Java project ('play new testapp')

When I call play run I get the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

As per the error above I've run the 'last' command and below is an extract from the stack trace that is produced from this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:203)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:278)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:478)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:500)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:616)
    at org.jboss.netty.logging.JdkLogger.debug(JdkLogger.java:36)
    at org.jboss.netty.logging.InternalLoggerFactory$1.debug(InternalLoggerFactory.java:80)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioProviderMetadata.<clinit>(NioProviderMetadata.java:95)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.<clinit>(NioWorker.java:58)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.<init>(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:58)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.<init>(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:133)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.<init>(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:104)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:43)
```

I fired up an Ubuntu VM and completed the same process and the app runs fine.
Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: I ran play classpath to get my classpath for the app and this was the output (replaced the common part of the directory with ...):

```
Here is the computed classpath of your application:

- .../testapp/target/scala-2.9.1/classes
- ...play-latest/framework/sbt/boot/scala-2.9.1/lib/scala-library.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/play/play_2.9.1/2.0/jars/play_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/play/templates_2.9.1/2.0/jars/templates_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/repository/local/com.github.scala-incubator.io/scala-io-file_2.9.1/0.2.0/jars/scala-io-file_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/repository/local/com.github.scala-incubator.io/scala-io-core_2.9.1/0.2.0/jars/scala-io-core_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/repository/local/com.github.jsuereth.scala-arm/scala-arm_2.9.1/0.3/jars/scala-arm_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/play/anorm_2.9.1/2.0/jars/anorm_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/io.netty/netty/3.3.0.Final/bundles/netty.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/jars/slf4j-api.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.6.4/jars/jul-to-slf4j.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.4/jars/jcl-over-slf4j.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.0/jars/logback-core.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.0/jars/logback-classic.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor/2.0/jars/akka-actor.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j/2.0/jars/akka-slf4j.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.google.guava/guava/10.0.1/jars/guava.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jars/jsr305.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.3/jars/ebean.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/jars/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.h2database/h2/1.3.158/jars/h2.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.scala-tools/scala-stm_2.9.1/0.4/jars/scala-stm_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.jolbox/bonecp/0.7.1.RELEASE/bundles/bonecp.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.9/bundles/snakeyaml.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.Final/jars/hibernate-validator.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/jars/validation-api.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.7.RELEASE/jars/spring-context.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.springframework/spring-core/3.0.7.RELEASE/jars/spring-core.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.0.7.RELEASE/jars/spring-beans.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/joda-time/joda-time/2.0/jars/joda-time.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.joda/joda-convert/1.1/jars/joda-convert.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/javassist/javassist/3.12.1.GA/jars/javassist.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/jars/commons-lang.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.ning/async-http-client/1.7.0/jars/async-http-client.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/oauth.signpost/signpost-core/1.2.1.1/jars/signpost-core.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/jars/commons-codec.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/com.codahale/jerkson_2.9.1/0.5.0/jars/jerkson_2.9.1.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.5/jars/jackson-core-asl.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.5/jars/jackson-mapper-asl.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.6/jars/reflections.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/jars/javax.servlet-api.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/javax.transaction/jta/1.1/jars/jta.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/tyrex/tyrex/1.0.1/jars/tyrex.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.3/jars/jaxen.jar
- ...play-latest/framework/../repository/local/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.0/jars/ehcache-core.jar
```

Comment: This classpath output seems to be ok. (you can compare with linux) Imho you should search in slf4j direction. BTW. Have you got newest version of JRE installed?

Comment: Hmmm... that is strange.  I am running Lion (10.7.3) with Java 1.6.0_31 installed and am using Play 2.0 with no problems.  I just created a new testapp as you described and it started with no hiccups.  The error that you are seeing seems to indicate that you are picking up an older slf4j jar somewhere in your environment.

Comment: @grahamrb: one more idea - try to move version 1.2.x to other folder, then in 2.0 version perform cleaning, then reload and update (in console), maybe it's some kind of cache, I had similar problem when changed PATH from 1.2 to 2.0, and after removing 1.2 folder it was fixed.

Comment: Do you use eclipse as your IDE, I think that I hade the same error untill I installed Scala - http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

Comment: @biesior, currently running Java 1.6.0_31-b04-414-11M3626 on my mac (which is the latest available from apple). I deleted all old versions of play and updated my path to point directly to the play 2 directory but am still getting the same error. No IDE at this stage, just command line.

Comment: Ok, starting to get somewhere, found that there is a plist file that defines the system classpath and it includes a directory which contains some slf4j classes. Specifically: /Library/Java/Extensions/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar /Library/Java/Extensions/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar Anyone else have these files on their mac? I've moved them out of the directory and it's now working! Not sure what was using these files, guess I'll find out when something refuses to start.